# how can I pass the context from both the class in the MODEL to one view without this error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

In a MODEL, I have two class - ContentDetails and CompetencyDetails which contains its properties

```
namespace CompetencyAssessmentServices.ServiceModel
{
    public class ContentDetails
    {
        public int CaseStudyId { get; set; }
        public string CaseStudy { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool ReviewStatus { get; set; }
        public string SolutionDescription { get; set; }
        public int CompetencyID { get; set; }
        public string CompetencyName { get; set; }
        public List<string> SolutionId { get; set; }

    }

    public class CompetencyDetails
    {
        public int CompID { get; set; }
        public string CompName { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Controller :

Action CaseStudy is retrieving the list of CompetencyDetails from database which is working fine.

```
namespace CompetencyAssessment.Controllers
{
    public class ContentManagementController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ContentManagement

        IContentManagementRepository repo = new ContentManagementRepository();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CaseStudy()
        {
            List<CompetencyDetails> complst = repo.GetCompetencyDetails();
            ViewBag.list = complst;
            return View(ViewBag.list);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CaseStudy(ContentDetails cd)
        {   
            ContentDetails ctd = repo.CaseStudyCreationDetails(cd);
            return View();
        }




    }
}
```

While loading the View, I am getting below error

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CompetencyAssessmentServices.ServiceModel.CompetencyDetails]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CompetencyAssessmentServices.ServiceModel.ContentDetails'.**

View is

```
@model CompetencyAssessmentServices.ServiceModel.ContentDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CASE-STUDY Contenet Creation (By SME)";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CASE-STUDY Contenet Creation (By SME)</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
         <h4>ContentDetails</h4>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseStudy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CaseStudy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "rows=20,columns=400" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseStudy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            Solution 1:   @Html.TextBox("Sol1")  @Html.DropDownList("CompetencyDetails", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "CompID", "CompName"), "Select Competency")
            Solution 2:   @Html.TextBox("Sol2")  @Html.DropDownList("CompetencyDetails", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "CompID", "CompName"), "Select Competency")
            Solution 3:   @Html.TextBox("Sol3")  @Html.DropDownList("CompetencyDetails", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "CompID", "CompName"), "Select Competency")
            Solution 4:   @Html.TextBox("Sol4")  @Html.DropDownList("CompetencyDetails", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "CompID", "CompName"), "Select Competency")

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SolutionId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SolutionId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SolutionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SolutionDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SolutionDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SolutionDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The reason, I am getting this error because my view contains the reference from both class CompetencyDetails and ContentDetails

Can someone please help on how can I pass the context from both the class in the MODEL without this error ?

PS: This is my first MVC project so would appreciate any various approaches to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

you can create new class having both the model class like example given below

```
public class Combine
{
    public List<ContentDetails> ContentDetailsList { get; set; }
    public ContentDetails ContentDetailsData { get; set; }
    public List<CompetencyDetails> CompetencyDetailsInfoList { get; set; }
    public CompetencyDetails CompetencyDetailsData { get; set; }
   
}
```

then in MVC controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CaseStudy()
    {
        var caseStudy = new SupplierDTO()
        {
            ContentDetailsList = db.ContentDetails.ToList(),
            CompetencyDetailsInfoList = db.CompetencyDetails.ToList(),
            
        };
        return View(caseStudy);
    }
```

then MVC View

```
@model CompetencyAssessmentServices.Models.Combine

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContentDetailsData.CaseStudy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContentDetailsData.CaseStudy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContentDetailsData .CaseStudy, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```